# How can I check for file extensions?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am trying to create a .bat script that checks if files are present and whether these files are .txt or .csv. When I run the script, it does not execute the exist command. What am I doing wrong? So far, I have this:

```
echo
cd C:\Users\Desktop
if exist "C:\Users\Desktop\*"
    (
        for /R "C:\Users\Desktop\" %%x in (*.csv) do
        (
            call another script
        )
    )
    else
    (
    echo Empty Directory.
    )
```

Comment: There are too many line-breaks in your code! type `if /?` and `for /?` in command prompt and read the help very carefully!

Comment: So I managed to do it. `if exist "*" (for /R %%x in (*.txt) do (something))`

Now my issue is that I want to be able to call logparser and execute against this .txt file. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually you don't need `if exist` at all here as `for /R` does not iterate if the given root directory does not exist anyway...

Comment: Very true. I also found out that I can pipe things into the command line as so: `echo logparser | SELECT * INTO file FROM file`

Answer (score -2):

You need to complete the command on the line... I got it working like so:

```
echo  
cd C:\Users\jimwh  
if exist "C:\Users\jimwh\*" (  
    for /R "C:\Users\jimwh\" %%x in (*.x*) do (  
       echo %%x  
    )  
)  
else (  
    echo Empty Directory.  
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I don't have to call the directory in the for loop.

Comment: This can't work, because `else` cannot be in a new line; see `if /?`...

Comment: I'm afraid, aschipfl is right. The `else` will throw an error.

Comment: @user2771365, `'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` appears, independent on whether `if exist` results in true or false! Also `cd C:\...` should be `cd /D "C:\..."`, and the file pattern `*.x*` makes no sense...